# Unable to run pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run a pom.xml that ultimately runs my java main class. On running the pom.xml I am getting the error:-

The pom.xml looks something like this (main class resides within ScreenShotUtility package):-

```
<build>  
 <plugins>  
  <plugin>  
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
   <version>1.1.1</version>  
   <executions>  
    <execution>  
     <phase>test</phase>  
     <goals>  
      <goal>java</goal>  
     </goals>  
     <configuration>  
      <mainClass>ScreenShotUtility.ScreenShotutility2</mainClass>  
      <arguments>  
       <argument>arg0</argument>
       <argument>arg1</argument>  
      </arguments>  
     </configuration>  
    </execution>  
   </executions>  
  </plugin>  
 </plugins>  
</build>  

<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Err what error...?

Comment: Please review your question, where is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<build>
  <defaultGoal>exec:java</defaultGoal>
...
</build>
```

to the pom and run

```
mvn
```

Why `exec:java`? Because it is a shorthand for `exec-maven-plugin:java` what is the name of the build-plugin.

Comment: added that. But still getting the error-Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:java (default) on project NA: An exception occured while executing the Java class. ScreenShotUtility.ScreenShotutility2 -> [Help 1]

Comment: @saketkumar Thats a bug.